# What is it called when it's snowing with the sun out?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

It is currently snowing, but the sun is shining. If it were raining while sunny, I would call that a sun shower. What is the equivalent for snow?

Comment: [This article](http://voices.washingtonpost.com/capitalweathergang/2009/02/in_his_recent_post_sunrise.html) agrees with the previous comment in calling them _sun snow showers_.

Comment: Wouldn't "sun flurry" be a more evocative term?

Comment: How about "It's snowing"? Is there a reason to change the phrase simply because the  "sun is out," whatever that means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sun snow shower](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22sun+snow+shower%22) comes to mind :)

Makes sense too

Answer (score 0):

[***sun snowburst***](http://365project.org/alophoto/365-year-2/2014-01-03)?

> The meteorological definition of a snowburst is as follows:
>
> "A short period of heavy snowfall, say on the order of 10-14 hours or so with snowfall rates around two inches per hour and greater. It is believed that snow frequently forms and falls out within "short" distances - say hundreds of feet. There is a tendency for the larger flakes to fall out closer to the shore."
>
> NOAA defines snowburst as:
>
> "Very intense shower of snow, often of short duration, that greatly restricts visibility and produces periods of rapid snow accumulation."
>
> [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowburst)